# am trying to run flutter app on ios simulator but am getting the problem

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Error (Xcode): Target debug_ios_bundle_flutter_assets failed: ShaderCompilerException: Shader compilation of "/Users/briankamau/Developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/shaders/ink_sparkle.frag" to "/Users/briankamau/my/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/App.framework/flutter_assets/shaders/ink_sparkle.frag" failed with exit code -9.

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro Max.

i expected it to launch